# Package syntax in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I found the following code assumed to be PLSQL:

```
package Z                                                                                                                                                                      
    V_LOT   NUMBER(17,2);                
    ...
end Z;
```

However, from the oracle documentation, it seems to be that "package" statement needs to have always a "create" before the "package" word.

Is this code correct?

thanks

Comment: I think that is the way the source code is stored in `all_source`. The `create` is implicit there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_package.htm) the `CREATE` statement is necessary, so your code is incorrect. It has to be like this:

```
create package z
is
  V_LOT   NUMBER(17,2);
  ...
end z;
```

Comment: Alternatively: "Create or replace"

Comment: @Rene thanks, fair point, I specified the bare minimum in creating packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below syntax for creating package

'create package ' or 'create or replace package '

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PACKAGE cust_sal AS
   PROCEDURE find_sal(c_id customers.id%type);
END cust_sal;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY cust_sal AS
   PROCEDURE find_sal(c_id customers.id%TYPE) IS
       c_sal customers.salary%TYPE;
   BEGIN
      SELECT salary INTO c_sal
      FROM customers
      WHERE id = c_id;
      dbms_output.put_line('Salary: '|| c_sal);
   END find_sal;
END cust_sal;
```